# How to make a popup settings page for an Android widget

Tags: android, input, popup, android-widget, settings

Ok so I am very new to the Android SDK, but not to programming. I want to attempt to make a simple Android widget. I've been looking around for things on the web pertaining to widgets, and have been able to find lots of information, but nothing pertaining to my main question.

How can I make a settings dialog that will adjust the widget when it is launched? When you add the Google search widget, it prompts you to specify what type of widget you want it to be. In my widget I'm making, I want to allow the user to specify the widget height right after they select it.

How can I present that type of dialog? What does that entail? Any code snippets or tutorials or help anyone has to offer will go a long way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here [How to put multiple widget sizes in one apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377810/how-to-put-multiple-widget-sizes-in-one-apk)
The answers quote resources for both several widgets in one paackage and configuration page. Still, the size choosing is done not in the own configure dislog, but during add.