# Android Widget Programming

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 4 different types of widgets in my app.
For each of the widget type, I have a Class derived from AppWidgetProvider  and a service which handles the periodic update to the widget.

Now I have to create different sizes widget for each type. If I keep 3 sizes for each widget, do I have to create 12 classes / services ?
Is there a better way ?

Any help / link to sample is welcome
thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. but try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377810/how-to-put-multiple-widget-sizes-in-one-apk

Comment: which part, i can explain

Comment: I guess this is what your looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981397/multiple-widget-sizes?lq=1

Comment: As per this article i have to create 12 receiver entries and 12 classes in my mainfest. Is there a better way?

Comment: that's the only way I know.

Comment: Phew. Android sucks in here