# Issue when implementing two AppWidgetProvider for two different Android Home Screen Widgets

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, widget, android-widget

### My Objective:

Create two Android Home Screen widgets for an app of two different sizes (3x2 & 5x2) as discussed in this StackOverflow question: [Multiple widget sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981397/multiple-widget-sizes). As mentioned, two classes that implement `AppWidgetProvider()` must be created that serve as the Kotlin business logic for each widget size. Each widget has its own layout `XML` and info  `XML`.

### The Implementation

```
EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt
package com.example.exampleapp

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.RemoteViews

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class EXAMPLEWidgetSmall : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {
    val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget_small)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

```
EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt
package com.example.exampleapp

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.RemoteViews

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class EXAMPLEWidgetMedium : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {
    val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget_medium)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

### The Error

```
e: 
/Users/example/examplefolder/exampleapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/exampleapp/EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt: (15, 13): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt
internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt
e: /Users/example/examplefolder/exampleapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/exampleapp/EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt: (28, 1): Conflicting overloads: internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt, internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt
e: /Users/example/examplefolder/exampleapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/exampleapp/EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt: (15, 13): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt
internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt
e: /Users/example/examplefolder/exampleapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/exampleapp/EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt: (28, 1): Conflicting overloads: internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetMedium.kt, internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int): Unit defined in com.example.exampleapp in file EXAMPLEWidgetSmall.kt
```

### The Issue

The issue seems to revolve around internal fun updateAppWidget being used in both files causing an overload resolution ambiguity. If I try to change the name of this function, another error is thrown, as this deviates from the important function of the `AppWidgetProvider()` class. In this StackOverflow answer: [How to add multiple widgets in the same app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570004/how-to-add-multiple-widgets-in-the-same-app?noredirect=1&lq=1), it is suggested that a "BaseWidget" class be created that implements `AppWidgetProvider()` and from which my two widget kt files would implement `BaseWidget()`. However I am unsure if this would solve the issue because I would still be trying to use the same internal function `updateAppWidget()`, nor how I would write this code (I am not familiar with Kotlin) because this var must vary in each file which defines each widget layout `val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget_small)`. How can I fix this issue so that the app can compile with no errors and for these widgets can work so that I can continue with their layout? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see both `AppWidgetProviders` are identical except for their layouts; so you would create an abstract parent class that has an abstract `Int` field for the layout int resource id that you must set in each widget sub-class with the corresponding layout resource.

And keep any shared code normally in the parent class. Now the `RemoteViews` can be implemented in the parent class with that `Int` field which has been set in the implemented child classes.

**Here's the implementation of that:**

**Parent class:**: make it abstract, add the abstract `widgetLayout` field; and keep the shared functionality

And for the error you face; you need to keep the internal fun `updateAppWidget` as a part of your parent class.

```
abstract class ParentWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    
    abstract var widgetLayout: Int // must be overiden by the child classes with the widget layout
    
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }


    private fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {
        val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, widgetLayout) //
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }
}
```

And override the `widgetLayout` in the child classes:

**Small widget**

```
class EXAMPLEWidgetSmall : ParentWidgetProvider() {

    override var widgetLayout
        get() = R.layout.example_widget_small
        set(_) {R.layout.example_widget_small}

}
```

**Medium widget (the same but with different layout file)**

```
class EXAMPLEWidgetMedium : ParentWidgetProvider() {

    override var widgetLayout
        get() = R.layout.example_widget_medium
        set(_) {R.layout.example_widget_medium}

}
```

Comment: Not sure how do you implement `onEnabled` & `onDisabled`, but you can differentiate between both widget using a when like `when(widgetLayout) { R.layout.example_widget_medium -> .... R.layout.example_widget_small->....}`